# Recover iPhone 4S keys without jailbreak?

Tags: jailbreak, siri

Ok so my father just got an iphone 4S, i have the 4. So i'm a big Siri hacker and i wanted to get his Siri keys. I would not like to jailbreak his phone though... So i was thinking, maybe i could put the phone on airplane mode and connect to my wifi and hook up my mac mini instead of my router. Then change the guzzon.apple.com to redirect to the mac mini in the hosts file. Then i run pysiri for getting the keys. Do you think this is a possible way of getting the keys without jailbreaking, or does anyone have a better idea? And if it comes down to it tell me that i'm gonna have to jailbreak to get those keys.

Comment: Sorry, but this question is out of scope.

Comment: So i just cant do it at all unless i get spire or Assistant4S

Comment: @sosborn why did you down vote, it hurts both of us, plus i was just wondering

Comment: Sorry - I didn't actually mean to down vote - don't know what happened there. But, these kind of questions don't really belong on StackOverflow. We look for more specific questions about programming problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Im afraid you will have to jailbreak the device. The server cant be spoofed and the key wont go through properly that way. Sorry, your gonna have to jailbreak.

Answer (score -1):

Applidium created a tool to let you get 4S keys without jailbreaking you phone.  You can see the code here: https://github.com/applidium/Cracking-Siri